# Windows 10 Fall Creators Update - removal of .NET 4.7.1

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, windows-10-v1709

As I understand Windows 10 Fall Creators Update includes .NET 4.7.1. It is possible to remove this .NET Framework version from this Windows 10 build? It looks like it is deeply integrated and can't be removed.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it.  A version of the .Net Framework has been included with Windows since Windows 7

Comment: Often .NET updates break some other software and it takes time to figure out if it is software which needs to be further fixed/updated or .NET itself :) Because of that we sometimes need not to use latest .NET or at least to investigate this possibility

Comment: So delay the 1709 update of that is the case.  .Net 4.7.1 is an in-place upgrade to .Net 4-4.7 how you use a specific version is done through targeting packs

Comment: If you were running 1703 you would be able to uninstall.Net 4.7.1 but due the fact your using 1709 that won’t  be possible.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033344/the-net-framework-4-7-1-web-installer-for-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Microsoft official information:

The .NET Framework 4.7.1 is included with:

Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709)
Windows Server 2016 (version 1709)

It's as a windows component, you can't remove it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10